# Multiple "Occur" result buffers in emacs?

Tags: emacs

Is there a package that allows me to have multiple *Occur* result buffer for the same buffer (like grep-a-lot: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/grep-a-lot.el).

I run into this issue when analyzing log files for multiple keywords (say to see what different but related threads were doing).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need an additional package. <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> will rename the current occur buffer to an unique name. You can add `occur-rename-buffer` to `occur-hook` to make it automatic (see the documentation of `occur-rename-buffer` which mentions this, too).

Comment: but then `g` does not reload occur buffer